# Need SQL Server query to aggregate data for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate

I have a table with customer information that I need to aggregate the data for into one row. My unique identifier is my customer number. How can i achieve that? Here is my current data:

```
        ID  CUST_NUM    CUSTOMER_NAME                       BOUGHT_PRODUCT_A    BOUGHT_PRODUCT_B  BOUGHT_PRODUCT_C  BOUGHT_PRODUCT_D
        1   125654      IHOP                                NULL                NULL              NULL              YES
        2   125654      I.H.O.P.                            YES                 NULL              NO                YES
        3   125654      IHOP INC.                           YES                 NULL              NULL              NULL
```

And this is my desired outcome:

```
        ID  CUST_NUM    CUSTOMER_NAME          BOUGHT_PRODUCT_A    BOUGHT_PRODUCT_B  BOUGHT_PRODUCT_C   BOUGHT_PRODUCT_D
        1   125654      IHOP,I.H.O.P.,IHOP INC. NULL                NULL              NULL              YES
```

Comment: BOUGHT_PRODUCT_D for example, what makes YES it's value in the aggregated result ? How does grouping YES, YES and NULL result in YES?

Comment: Yes means my customer purchased the product under a different name so as long as there is a YES for that product in any of the rows the result will be YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *window* function:

```
select distinct CUST_NUM,
       stuff ((select distinct ',' +CUSTOMER_NAME  
               from table 
               where t.CUST_NUM = CUST_NUM for xml path('')
               ), 1,1, ''
             ) as CUSTOMER_NAME, 
       first_value(BOUGHT_PRODUCT_A) over (partition by CUST_NUM order by ID) BOUGHT_PRODUCT_A,
       first_value(BOUGHT_PRODUCT_B) over (partition by CUST_NUM order by ID) BOUGHT_PRODUCT_B,
       first_value(BOUGHT_PRODUCT_C) over (partition by CUST_NUM order by ID) BOUGHT_PRODUCT_C,
       first_value(BOUGHT_PRODUCT_D) over (partition by CUST_NUM order by ID) BOUGHT_PRODUCT_D
from table t;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, I am getting the following error: Incorrect syntax near 'first_value'.

Comment: @Teeko. . . Comma missing.